# Использование локальных переменных в рекурсии

Tags: c++, c, рекурсия

Стоит ли использовать локальные переменные внутри рекурсии?
При каждом вызове рекурсивной функции переменные заново создаются и инициализируются?

Comment: Да. Да и да. Если вы не будете использовать локальные переменные, то чем будут различаться состояния разных вызовов? А если нет различий, то как вы будете продвигаться к решению задачи? (к локальным переменным я отношу и параметры функции, функционально они ничем не отличаются).

Answer (score 2):

Короткий ответ. Да, создаются. Инициализируется ли - зависит от Вас. Стоит ли использовать? а почему бы и нет.

Длиннее ответ. Локальные переменные создаются на стеке. Создание переменных на стеке очень быстро. Если нужно создать "простые типы" - int/char/float, то это просто изменить значение указателя стека (то есть, пара инструкций процессора). Присвоить int переменной значение (инициализировать) - то же очень быстро.

А вот уже с переменными, которые хранят объекты (типа класс) все не так однозначно и нужно каждый раз смотреть. Для таких переменных гарантированно вызывается конструктор (для int переменной никто не будет за Вас делать "инициализацию"), а конструктор может сделать очень и очень много.

Но нужно не забывать ещё об одном - стек не бесконечный. На 32битных платформах он обычно около 1 мегабайта, на 64 - до 8 мегабайт. Если создавать немного, то все будет работать. А если на стеке создавать массивы на сотни килобайт, то стек очень быстро исчерпается. Также не стоит забывать, что для рекурсивного вызова нужно ещё сохранить адрес возврата, а это ещё 4-8 байт минимум и параметры передать.

Comment: Если поминать адрес возврата, то стоит указать и на более затратное по памяти сохранение регистров.

Comment: там много чего ещё можно вспомнить. Но умный компилятор может схитрить и не сохранять регистры

Comment: А в пределе, он может заменить рекурсию итерацией и заинлайнить код, разместив все переменные в регистрах

Comment: а может и вообще все выбросить, предвычислив все. Чем более просто написан код, тем более легче компилятору улучшить код. Но с рекурсией на самом деле страшно другое - это большое кол-во вызовов (например, если пытаться вычислить числа Фибоначчи).